# What's the difference between ConcurrentHashMap and Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)?

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency

I have a Map which is to be modified by several threads concurrently.

There seem to be three different synchronized Map implementations in the Java API:

- `Hashtable`
- `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)`
- `ConcurrentHashMap`

From what I understand, `Hashtable` is an old implementation (extending the obsolete `Dictionary` class), which has been adapted later to fit the `Map` interface. While it *is* synchronized, it seems to have serious [scalability issues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233.html) and is discouraged for new projects.

But what about the other two? What are the differences between Maps returned by `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)` and `ConcurrentHashMap`s? Which one fits which situation?

Comment: @SmilesinaJar Link is currently broken, here is an archived copy of this article: [Why ConcurrentHashMap is better than Hashtable and just as good as a HashMap](https://web.archive.org/web/20140604083201/http://www.codercorp.com/blog/java/why-concurrenthashmap-is-better-than-hashtable-and-just-as-good-hashmap.html)

Comment: IBM: How ConcurrentHashMap offers higher concurrency without
compromising thread safety @
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/j-jtp08223-pdf.pdf

Comment: FYI, Java 6 brought [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) as another thread-safe `Map` implementation. Designed to be highly concurrent under load, using [Skip List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) algorithm.

Answer (score 448, accepted):

For your needs, use `ConcurrentHashMap`. It allows concurrent modification of the Map from several threads without the need to block them. `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` creates a blocking Map which will degrade performance, albeit ensure consistency (if used properly).

Use the second option if you need to ensure data consistency, and each thread needs to have an up-to-date view of the map. Use the first if performance is critical, and each thread only inserts data to the map, with reads happening less frequently.

Comment: Looking at the source code, the synchronized map is only an implementation with one mutex (blocking) while the ConcurrentHashMap is more complex to deal with concurrent access

Comment: Please also note that the ConcurrentHashMap does not allow null keys or values. So they are NOT equal alternatives of a synchronized map.

Comment: I think you should read this [http://ria101.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/concurrenthashmap-avoid-a-common-misuse/](http://ria101.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/concurrenthashmap-avoid-a-common-misuse/)

Comment: "`Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` creates a blocking Map which will degrade performance, albeit ensure consistency (if used properly)": Is not the creation `Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...))` sufficient to ensure consistency? Is there anything else I need to be aware of?

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh The issue raised in that article has been fixed in Java 7 and further improvements have been made in Java 8.

Comment: @hengxin: as soon as you are performing an operation consisting of multiple queries or updates of the map or when you are iterating over the map, you have to manually synchronize on the map to ensure consistency. The synchronized maps guarantee consistency only for single operations (method invocations) on the map, which makes it more than often worthless as most real life operations are non-trivial so you have to manually synchronize anyway.

Answer (score 257):

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║   Property    ║     HashMap       ║    Hashtable      ║  ConcurrentHashMap  ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╩═════════════════════╣ 
║      Null     ║     allowed       ║              not allowed                ║
║  values/keys  ║                   ║                                         ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Thread-safety ║                   ║                                         ║
║   features    ║       no          ║                  yes                    ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╦═════════════════════╣
║     Lock      ║       not         ║ locks the whole   ║ locks the portion   ║        
║  mechanism    ║    applicable     ║       map         ║                     ║ 
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════════╩═══════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║   Iterator    ║               fail-fast               ║ weakly consistent   ║ 
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Regarding locking mechanism:
`Hashtable` [locks the object](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29), while `ConcurrentHashMap` locks [only the bucket](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.putVal%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cboolean%29).

Comment: `Hashtable` is not locking portion of map. Look at the implementation. It is using `synchronized` key with no lock provided so it basically means that it lock whole `hashtable` in each operation.

Comment: What about the synchronizedMap?

Comment: Collections.syncronizedMap behaviour is like the backing map, except all the methods are thread-safe

Comment: I would print the table and sell it for $5 each ;). Good one @shevchyk

Comment: Edited: Neither are fully thread safe. That is a bit misleading for newer developers.  See: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233/index.html to understand that even ConcurrentHashMap is not fully thread-safe from external data-races. (eg: 1 thread removes a value and another later tries check if it is present and to put it if not. That is a data race condition and still means that despite using a "ConcurrentHashMap" you are not alleviated of all thread safety issues.

Answer (score 148):

The "scalability issues" for `Hashtable` are present in exactly the same way in `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)` - they use very simple synchronization, which means that only one thread can access the map at the same time.

This is not much of an issue when you have simple inserts and lookups (unless you do it extremely intensively), but becomes a big problem when you need to iterate over the entire Map, which can take a long time for a large Map - while one thread does that, all others have to wait if they want to insert or lookup anything.

The `ConcurrentHashMap` uses very sophisticated techniques to reduce the need for synchronization and allow parallel read access by multiple threads without synchronization and, more importantly, provides an `Iterator` that requires no synchronization and even allows the Map to be modified during interation (though it makes no guarantees whether or not elements that were inserted during iteration will be returned).

Comment: Now that's what I wanted! :)
The no-synchronized Iterator is just pure sweetness alone!
Thansk for the info! :) (:

Comment: Great answer..but does it mean during retrieval thread will not get the latest updates since reader threads are not in sync.

Comment: @MrA: Are you asking about the ConcurrentHashMap? And what do you mean by "retrieval"?

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt for ConcurrentHashmap for eg. suppose there are multiple threads. some of them are updating the Map and some of them are getting data from that same map. SO in this scenario when threads are trying to read is it guaranteed  that they will get the latest data that has been updated since reader threads does not have to hold locks.

Answer (score 38):

The main difference between these two is that `ConcurrentHashMap` will lock only portion of the data which are being updated while other portion of data can be accessed by other threads. However, `Collections.synchronizedMap()` will lock all the data while updating, other threads can only access the data when the lock is released. If there are many update operations and relative small amount of read operations, you should choose `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Also one other difference is that `ConcurrentHashMap` will not preserve the order of elements in the Map passed in. It is similar to `HashMap` when storing data. There is no guarantee that the element order is preserved. While `Collections.synchronizedMap()` will preserve the elements order of the Map passed in. For example, if you pass a `TreeMap` to `ConcurrentHashMap`, the elements order in the `ConcurrentHashMap` may not be the same as the order in the `TreeMap`, but `Collections.synchronizedMap()` will preserve the order.

Furthermore, `ConcurrentHashMap` can guarantee that there is no `ConcurrentModificationException` thrown while one thread is updating the map and another thread is traversing the iterator obtained from the map. However, `Collections.synchronizedMap()` is not guaranteed on this.

There is [one post](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1394026282-ConcurrentHashMap-vs-Collections-synchronizedMap%28%29) which demonstrate the differences of these two and also the `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

Answer (score 35):

ConcurrentHashMap is preferred when you can use it - though it requires at least Java 5.

It is designed to scale well when used by multiple threads. Performance may be marginally poorer when only a single thread accesses the Map at a time, but significantly better when multiple threads access the map concurrently.

I found a [blog entry](https://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2007/04/performance-comparision-between.html) that reproduces a table from the excellent book [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/), which I thoroughly recommend.

Collections.synchronizedMap makes sense really only if you need to wrap up a map with some other characteristics, perhaps some sort of ordered map, like a TreeMap.

Comment: Yeah - seems I mention that book in every other answer I make!

Comment: @BillMichell link is broken

Comment: @Govinda Turn off javascript before accessing the link. The blog entry is still there!

Answer (score 16):

**Synchronized Map:**

Synchronized Map is also not very different than Hashtable and provides similar performance in concurrent Java programs. Only difference between Hashtable and SynchronizedMap is that SynchronizedMap is not a legacy and you can wrap any Map to create it’s synchronized version by using Collections.synchronizedMap() method.

**ConcurrentHashMap:**

The ConcurrentHashMap class provides a concurrent version of the standard HashMap. This is an improvement on the synchronizedMap functionality provided in the Collections class.

Unlike Hashtable and Synchronized Map, it never locks whole Map, instead it divides the map in segments and locking is done on those. It perform better if number of reader threads are greater than number of writer threads.

ConcurrentHashMap by default is separated into 16 regions and locks are applied. This default number can be set while initializing a ConcurrentHashMap instance. When setting data in a particular segment, the lock for that segment is obtained. This means that two updates can still simultaneously execute safely if they each affect separate buckets, thus minimizing lock contention and so maximizing performance.

ConcurrentHashMap doesn’t throw a ConcurrentModificationException

ConcurrentHashMap doesn’t throw a ConcurrentModificationException if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it

**Difference between synchornizedMap and ConcurrentHashMap**

Collections.synchornizedMap(HashMap)  will return a collection which is almost equivalent to Hashtable, where every modification operation on Map is locked on Map object while in case of ConcurrentHashMap, thread-safety is achieved by dividing whole Map into different partition based upon concurrency level and only locking particular portion instead of locking whole Map.

ConcurrentHashMap does not allow null keys or null values while synchronized HashMap allows one null keys.

**Similar links**

[Link1](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/difference-between-concurrenthashmap.html)

[Link2](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1394026282-ConcurrentHashMap-vs-Collections-synchronizedMap%28%29)

[Performance Comparison](http://www.programering.com/a/MzM4MjNwATE.html)

Answer (score 14):

In `ConcurrentHashMap`, the lock is applied to a segment instead of an entire Map.
Each segment manages its own internal hash table. The lock is applied only for update operations. `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)` synchronizes the entire map.

Answer (score 12):

- [`Hashtable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) and [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) do not allow `null` keys or `null` values.
- [`Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) synchronizes **all** operations (`get`, `put`, `size`, etc).
- [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) supports full concurrency of retrievals, and adjustable expected concurrency for updates.

As usual, there are concurrency--overhead--speed tradeoffs involved. You really need to consider the detailed concurrency requirements of your application to make a decision, and then test your code to see if it's good enough.

Answer (score 9):

You are right about `HashTable`, you can forget about it.

[Your article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233.html) mentions the fact that while HashTable and the synchronized wrapper class provide basic thread-safety by only allowing one thread at a time to access the map, this is not 'true' thread-safety since many compound operations still require additional synchronization, for example:

```
synchronized (records) {
  Record rec = records.get(id);
  if (rec == null) {
      rec = new Record(id);
      records.put(id, rec);
  }
  return rec;
}
```

However, don't think that `ConcurrentHashMap` is a simple alternative for a `HashMap` with a typical `synchronized` block as shown above. Read [this](http://dmy999.com/article/34/correct-use-of-concurrenthashmap) article to understand its intricacies better.

Answer (score 7):

Here are few :

1) ConcurrentHashMap locks only portion of Map but SynchronizedMap locks whole MAp.
2) ConcurrentHashMap has better performance over SynchronizedMap and more scalable.
3) In case of multiple reader and Single writer ConcurrentHashMap is best choice.

This text is from [Difference between ConcurrentHashMap and hashtable in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/difference-between-concurrenthashmap.html)

Answer (score 7):

**ConcurrentHashMap**

- ConcurrentHashMap for performance-critical applications where there are far more write operations than there are read operations.
- It is thread safe without synchronizing the whole map.
- Reads can happen very fast while write is done with a lock.
- There is no locking at the object level.
- The locking is at a much finer granularity at a hashmap bucket level.
- ConcurrentHashMap doesn’t throw a ConcurrentModificationException if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it.
- ConcurrentHashMap uses multitude of locks.
- read operations are non-blocking, whereas write operations take a lock on a particular segment or bucket.

**SynchronizedHashMap**

- Synchronization at Object level.
- Every read/write operation needs to acquire lock.
- Locking the entire collection is a performance overhead.
- This essentially gives access to only one thread to the entire map & blocks all the other threads.
- It may cause contention.
- SynchronizedHashMap returns Iterator, which fails-fast on concurrent modification.

**Collection.synchronizedMap()**

- The Collections utility class provides polymorphic algorithms that operate on collections and return wrapped collections. Its synchronizedMap() method provides thread-safe functionality.
- We need to use, Collections.synchronizedMap() when data consistency is of utmost importance.

[source](http://crunchify.com/hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronizedmap-how-a-hashmap-can-be-synchronized-in-java/)

Answer (score 7):

We can achieve thread safety by using ConcurrentHashMap and synchronisedHashmap and Hashtable. But there is a lot of difference if you look at their architecture.

1. **synchronisedHashmap and Hashtable**

> Both will maintain the lock at the object level. So if you want to perform any operation like put/get then you have to acquire the lock first. At the same time, other threads are not allowed to perform any operation. So at a time, only one thread can operate on this. So the waiting time will increase here. We can say that performance is relatively low when you comparing with ConcurrentHashMap.

2. **ConcurrentHashMap**

> It will maintain the lock at segment level. It has 16 segments and maintains the concurrency level as 16 by default. So at a time, 16 threads can be able to operate on ConcurrentHashMap. Moreover, read operation doesn't require a lock. So any number of threads can perform a get operation on it.
>
> If thread1 wants to perform put operation in segment 2 and thread2 wants to perform put operation on segment 4 then it is allowed here. Means, 16 threads can perform update(put/delete) operation on ConcurrentHashMap at a time.
>
> So that the waiting time will be less here. Hence the performance is relatively better than synchronisedHashmap and Hashtable.

Comment: ,1. what happens if multiple thread tries to edit the same block ? 2. What happens if  say two threads tries to read data from the same block where another thread if writing data at the same time ?

Answer (score 5):

ConcurrentHashMap is optimized for concurrent access.

Accesses don't lock the whole map but use a finer grained strategy, which improves scalability.  There are also functional enhanvements specifically for concurrent access, e.g. concurrent iterators.

Answer (score 4):

There is **one critical feature** to note about `ConcurrentHashMap` other than concurrency feature it provides, which is **fail-safe** iterator. I have seen developers using `ConcurrentHashMap` just because they want to edit the entryset - put/remove while iterating over it. 
`Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)` does not provide **fail-safe** iterator but it provides **fail-fast** iterator instead. fail-fast iterators uses snapshot of the size of map which can not be edited during iteration.

Answer (score 3):

1. If Data Consistency is highly important - Use Hashtable or Collections.synchronizedMap(Map).
2. If speed/performance is highly important and Data Updating can be compromised- Use ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want to use the `ConcurrentHashMap` make sure you are ready to miss 'updates'
 (i.e. printing contents of the HashMap does not ensure it will print the up-to-date Map) and use APIs like `CyclicBarrier` to ensure consistency across your program's lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Collections.synchronizedMap() method synchronizes all the methods of the HashMap and effectively reduces it to a data structure where one thread can enter at a time because it locks every method on a common lock.

In ConcurrentHashMap synchronization is done a little differently. Rather than locking every method on a common lock, ConcurrentHashMap uses separate lock for separate buckets thus locking only a portion of the Map.
By default there are 16 buckets and also separate locks for separate buckets. So the default concurrency level is 16. That means theoretically any given time 16 threads can access ConcurrentHashMap if they all are going to separate buckets.

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentHashMap was presented as alternative to Hashtable in Java 1.5 as part of concurrency package. With ConcurrentHashMap, you have a better choice not only if it can be safely used in the concurrent multi-threaded environment but also provides better performance than Hashtable and synchronizedMap. ConcurrentHashMap performs better because it locks a part of Map. It allows concurred read operations and the same time maintains integrity by synchronizing write operations.

### How ConcurrentHashMap is implemented

ConcurrentHashMap was developed as alternative of Hashtable and support all functionality of Hashtable with additional ability, so called concurrency level. ConcurrentHashMap allows multiple readers to read simultaneously without using blocks. It becomes possible by separating Map to different parts and blocking only part of Map in updates. By default, concurrency level is 16, so Map is spitted to 16 parts and each part is managed by separated block. It means, that 16 threads can work with Map simultaneously, if they work with different parts of Map. It makes ConcurrentHashMap hight productive, and not to down thread-safety.

If you are interested in some important features of ConcurrentHashMap and when you should use this realization of Map - I just put a link to a good article - [How to use ConcurrentHashMap in Java](http://poltora.info/blog/how-to-use-concurrenthashmap-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Besides what has been suggested, I'd like to post the source code related to `SynchronizedMap`.

To make a `Map` thread safe, we can use `Collections.synchronizedMap` statement and input the map instance as the parameter.

The implementation of `synchronizedMap` in `Collections` is like below

```
   public static <K,V> Map<K,V> synchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m) {
        return new SynchronizedMap<>(m);
    }
```

As you can see, the input `Map` object is wrapped by the `SynchronizedMap` object.
Let's dig into the implementation of `SynchronizedMap` ,

```
 private static class SynchronizedMap<K,V>
        implements Map<K,V>, Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1978198479659022715L;

        private final Map<K,V> m;     // Backing Map
        final Object      mutex;        // Object on which to synchronize

        SynchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m) {
            this.m = Objects.requireNonNull(m);
            mutex = this;
        }

        SynchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m, Object mutex) {
            this.m = m;
            this.mutex = mutex;
        }

        public int size() {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.size();}
        }
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.isEmpty();}
        }
        public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.containsKey(key);}
        }
        public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.containsValue(value);}
        }
        public V get(Object key) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.get(key);}
        }

        public V put(K key, V value) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.put(key, value);}
        }
        public V remove(Object key) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.remove(key);}
        }
        public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
            synchronized (mutex) {m.putAll(map);}
        }
        public void clear() {
            synchronized (mutex) {m.clear();}
        }

        private transient Set<K> keySet;
        private transient Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet;
        private transient Collection<V> values;

        public Set<K> keySet() {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                if (keySet==null)
                    keySet = new SynchronizedSet<>(m.keySet(), mutex);
                return keySet;
            }
        }

        public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                if (entrySet==null)
                    entrySet = new SynchronizedSet<>(m.entrySet(), mutex);
                return entrySet;
            }
        }

        public Collection<V> values() {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                if (values==null)
                    values = new SynchronizedCollection<>(m.values(), mutex);
                return values;
            }
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o)
                return true;
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.equals(o);}
        }
        public int hashCode() {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.hashCode();}
        }
        public String toString() {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.toString();}
        }

        // Override default methods in Map
        @Override
        public V getOrDefault(Object k, V defaultValue) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.getOrDefault(k, defaultValue);}
        }
        @Override
        public void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
            synchronized (mutex) {m.forEach(action);}
        }
        @Override
        public void replaceAll(BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> function) {
            synchronized (mutex) {m.replaceAll(function);}
        }
        @Override
        public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.putIfAbsent(key, value);}
        }
        @Override
        public boolean remove(Object key, Object value) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.remove(key, value);}
        }
        @Override
        public boolean replace(K key, V oldValue, V newValue) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.replace(key, oldValue, newValue);}
        }
        @Override
        public V replace(K key, V value) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.replace(key, value);}
        }
        @Override
        public V computeIfAbsent(K key,
                Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.computeIfAbsent(key, mappingFunction);}
        }
        @Override
        public V computeIfPresent(K key,
                BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.computeIfPresent(key, remappingFunction);}
        }
        @Override
        public V compute(K key,
                BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.compute(key, remappingFunction);}
        }
        @Override
        public V merge(K key, V value,
                BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.merge(key, value, remappingFunction);}
        }

        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
            synchronized (mutex) {s.defaultWriteObject();}
        }
    }
```

What `SynchronizedMap` does can be summarized as adding a single lock to primary method of the input `Map` object. All method guarded by the lock can't be accessed by multiple threads at the same time. That means normal operations like `put` and `get` can be executed by a single thread at the same time for all data in the `Map` object.

It makes the `Map` object thread safe now but the performance may become an issue in some scenarios.

The `ConcurrentMap` is far more complicated in the implementation, we can refer to [Building a better HashMap](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/index.html) for details. In a nutshell, it's implemented taking both thread safe and performance into consideration.