# examples of ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I was reading the article "[Java theory and practice: Building a better HashMap](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/)" that gives an excellent overview about the implementation of ConcurrentHashMap.

I also found some discussions over it on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510632/whats-the-difference-between-concurrenthashmap-and-collections-synchronizedmapm).

I question though I had in my mind is "what are the scenarios/applications/places" where ConcurrentHashMap is used.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use it for quick lookup from user ids to user objects in a multi-threaded server for instance.

I have a network-thread, a timer thread for periodical tasks and a thread for handling console input. Multiple threads access the hash map of users, thus it needs to be thread safe.

Answer (score 6):

You would use a `ConcurrentHashMap` in the same instances you would use a `HashMap`, except that you plan on more than one thread using the map.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ConcurrentHashMap` is recommended for large Maps or large number of read-write operations due to:

- When reading from the map, it's not locked. Thus, if 5 threads are reading from it, all of them can simultaneously read from map.
- On writing, only the relevant record (key) is locked. Thus, if 5 threads are writing values of different keys, all those operations can happen simultaneously. However, if 2 threads are writing to same key, those operations are thread-safe. That happens because there is no locking at the object (map) level but at a much finer granularity - at a hashmap bucket level.

Consider the following example:

```
public class ConcurrentHashMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //ConcurrentHashMap
        Map<String,String> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
        myMap.put("1", "1");
        myMap.put("2", "1");
        myMap.put("3", "1");
        myMap.put("4", "1");
        myMap.put("5", "1");
        myMap.put("6", "1");
        System.out.println("ConcurrentHashMap before iterator: "+myMap);
        Iterator<String> itr1 = myMap.keySet().iterator();

        while(itr1.hasNext()){
            String key = itr1.next();
            if(key.equals("3")) myMap.put(key+"new", "new3");
        }
        System.out.println("ConcurrentHashMap after iterator: "+myMap);

        //HashMap
        myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        myMap.put("1", "1");
        myMap.put("2", "1");
        myMap.put("3", "1");
        myMap.put("4", "1");
        myMap.put("5", "1");
        myMap.put("6", "1");
        System.out.println("HashMap before iterator: "+myMap);
        Iterator<String> itr2 = myMap.keySet().iterator();

        while(itr2.hasNext()){
            String key = itr2.next();
            if(key.equals("3")) myMap.put(key+"new", "new3");
        }
        System.out.println("HashMap after iterator: "+myMap);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
ConcurrentHashMap before iterator: {1=1, 5=1, 6=1, 3=1, 4=1, 2=1}
ConcurrentHashMap after iterator: {1=1, 3new=new3, 5=1, 6=1, 3=1, 4=1, 2=1}
HashMap before iterator: {3=1, 2=1, 1=1, 6=1, 5=1, 4=1}
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:828)
    at com.test.ConcurrentHashMapExample.main(ConcurrentHashMapExample.java:44)
```

As you can see, for the `HashMap` a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown  because you trying to change a map that you currently iterating on! (specifically, the exception will be thrown on the statement : `String key = itr1.next();`)