# Specific usage of Hashtable over ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, hashtable, concurrenthashmap

`ConcurrentHashMap` was introduced in 1.5 as a part java `java.util.concurrent` package. Before that the only way to have a `threadsafe` map was to use `HashTable` or `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)`.

For all the practical purpose (multithread environment),`ConcurrentHashMap` is sufficient to address the needs except one case wherein a thread needs a ***uniform view*** of the map.

My question is, apart from having a Uniform View of the map, are there any other scenarios wherein `ConcurrentHashMap` is not an option ?

Comment: You might find some cases where one or the other is less performant than you require. Perhaps when heavily loaded. You would need to measure these things though.

Comment: What is "uniform view"? Could you please explain...

Comment: @yegor256, a uniform view is a view of the entries of the map which is not changing when the thread is access this particular map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a stretch but I will give it as a use case.

If you needed a thread-safe Map implementation which you can do some extra compound operation on which isn't available via `ConcurrentMap`.  Let's say you want to ensure two other objects don't exist before adding a third.

```
Hashtable t = new Hashtable();

synchronized(t){
   if(!t.contains(object1) && !t.contains(object2)){
      t.put(object3,object3);
   }
}
```

Again this is a stretch, but you would not be able to achieve this with a CHM while ensuring atomicity and thread-safety.  Because all operations of a `Hashtable` and its `synchronizedMap` counter part synchronize on the instance of the Map this ensures thread-safety.

At the end of the day I would seldom, if ever, use a `synchronizedMap`/`Hashtable` and I suggest you should do the same.

Answer (score 4):

The usage of `Hashtable` has been discouraged since Java 1.2 and the utility of `synchronizedMap` is quite limited and almost always ends up being insufficient due to the too-fine granularity of locking. However, when you do have a scenario where individual updates are the grain size you need, `ConcurrentHashMap` is a no-brainer better choice over `synchronizedMap`. It has better concurrency, thread-safe iterators (no, `synchronizedMap` **doesn't** have those—this is due to its design as a wrapper around a non-thread-safe map), better overall performance, and very little extra memory weight to pay for it all.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, `ConcurrentMap` is a replacement of `HashTable` and `Collections.synchronizedMap()` for thread-safe purposes. A usage of that all classes is discouraged. Thus, the answer to your question is "no, there are no other scenarios".

See also: [What's the difference between ConcurrentHashMap and Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510632)