# Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap()); is not making Map threadsafe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm using following construct for creating a threadsafe `Map`.

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap());
```

Though I'm getting `ConcurrentModificationException` error.

Comment: you could use a HashTable which is thread safe

Comment: @user1479853 `HashTable` use is discouraged by the Java community.

Comment: @user1479853 .... and it won't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 8):

Without code it is hard to guess what is the real issue, but my guess is, you are not using  returned collection to perform operations. As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29)

> In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing collection is accomplished through the returned collection.
>   It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned collection when iterating over it:

```
  Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);
     ...
  synchronized(c) {
      Iterator i = c.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
         foo(i.next());
  }
```

Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: The problem would be avoided by using a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of  `Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);`.

Answer (score 5):

Not to detract from any of the other answers here, but this code below shows that concurrent modification has little to do with actual multithreading.  It's caused when you say, iterate over a collection but modify it while you are iterating....

```
  List list = new ArrayList();
  list.add("1");
  list.add("2");

  Iterator i = list.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
      Object value = i.next();  // throws java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

      list.add("another");  
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, the solution to not get a `ConcurrentModificationException` in your code would be using a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap());`. Explanation here:

- [What's the difference between ConcurrentHashMap and Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510632/1065197)

As Nambari says, the problem is harder to identify without actual code. Note that this `Map` only protects the objects that contains. Still, you can modify a same object instance in a method:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object();
//fill the map...
map.put("data", new Data());

//and now we have this unsynchronized method that two or more threads can access at the same time
public void modifyData(String key, int newDataIntValue) {
    //this is synchronized by the ConcurrentHashMap
    Data data = map.get(key);
    //this isn't
    //you can get problems here...
    data.setIntValue(newDataIntValue);
}
```

The synchronized collection **won't** save your code for these cases. You should synchronize this method by yourself.

Additional info: if you're trying to implement a cache library or the [Flyweight design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight), don't reinvent the wheel and use a proven and tested framework like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) or [jboss cache](http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the java doc

Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) map backed by the specified map. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing map is accomplished through the returned map.
It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views:

```
  Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
  ...
  Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
  ...
  synchronized(m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
      Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
       while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
   }
```

Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior. 
The returned map will be serializable if the specified map is serializable.

Parameters:
m the map to be "wrapped" in a synchronized map.
Returns:
a synchronized view of the specified map.

Comment: Your synchronization won't work for 2 threads accessing this method at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized has nothing to do with ConcurrentModificationException since it can be take place in a single-threaded environment if you do attempt to remove list item while iterating over the list, using the list's remove method.

Synchronized only guarantees you serial access.