# What's the easiest way to make sure that when one thread updates a map, another thread will see this update?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I need to have a number of threads which operate on the shared java.util.HashMap.

Each of them will perform single read and write operations (i.e. none will use bulk operations, like `putAll()`) and I want to make sure there will be no lost updates.

Does synchronized writing guarantees safety? If I do something like this:

```
writeLock.lock();
double latestValue = map.get(key);
map.put(key, latestValue + diff);
writeLock.unlock();
```

Will it be enough to avoid lost updates? Will the same approach be enough to achieve repeatable reads?

And, if I used `ConcurrentHashMap`, can I get rid of my `locks` safely?

UPD: is there any linear overhead in memory usage if I switch from HashMap to ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: you have answered your own question , here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510632/whats-the-difference-between-concurrenthashmap-and-collections-synchronizedmap

Answer (score 2):

Doing updates in synchronized block or after acquiring a lock doesn't guarantee that you will see up-to-date values. For seeing updated/fresh values you are required to take lock for reading as well.

```
// while writing
lock.lock();
 try {
 map.put(key, value);
}finally {
  lock.unlock();
}

// while reading
lock.lock();
 try {
   map.get(key);
 }finally{
  lock.unlock()
}
```

And yes `ConcurrentHashMap` is suited best for your purpose. and you don't need locks either.

Comment: +1.  There's also the danger of reading the map while it's being modified and getting an exception, but that's unlikely and you'll know it when it happens.  Not seeing updates is insidious and can go unnoticed for a long time.

Comment: @RalphChapin: it’s not that unlikely as it happens in real life. Further, you’re not only risking exceptions but lots of different kind of bugs due to reading stale values. One infamous issue is getting into an infinite loop inside `HashMap.get`…

Answer (score 0):

The read/write lock you demonstrate is clearly up to the task, since that's what it's designed to do.

However, since you seem to be mostly updating existing values, you could consider populating your map with AtomicIntegers or similar.