# How to sync multi thread map update

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm wondering how to sync the following multi thread so that I can still run the threads in parallel without causing multiple objects to be saved.

```
public void setupRender() {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    final Map<Integer, String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, String>());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                parse(map); 
            }
        });
        System.out.println("map size " + map.size() + " loop " + i);
    }
}

public void parse(Map<Integer, String> map) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if (map.containsKey(j)) {
            System.out.println("Update");
            //session.update(map.getKey(j));
        } else {
            System.out.println("add to map " + j);
            String obj = "test";
            map.put(j, obj);
            System.out.println("save");
            //session.save(obj);
        }

        if (j % 50 == 0) {
            System.out.println("commit");
            //tx.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Outcome, notice how multiple objects of the same key are added to the map, but worse yet saved to the database resulting in duplicate database enteries.

```
map size 0 loop 0
map size 0 loop 1
add to map 0
commit
add to map 1
add to map 0
commit
add to map 2
add to map 3
add to map 4
add to map 2
add to map 5
add to map 6
map size 1 loop 2
add to map 7
add to map 8
add to map 9
commit
map size 10 loop 3
commit
add to map 5
```

Comment: Can you just set the transaction isolation level on the db driver?

Comment: I don't see how that would work when the db just sees it as a completely new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ConcurrentHashMap` and `putIfAbsent` to guarantee consistency and performance. In this case your session updates can run simultaneously.

```
putIfAbsent:
    - returns the previous value associated with the specified key, 
      or null if there was no mapping for the key

public void parse(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {    
        String obj = "test";

        Object returnedValue = map.putIfAbsent(j, obj);

        boolean wasInMap = returnedValue != null;

        if (wasInMap) {
            System.out.println("Update");
            //session.update(map.getKey(j));
        } else {
            System.out.println("add to map " + j);

            map.put(j, obj);
            System.out.println("save");
            //session.save(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also put there a callback which would create a new instance conditionally:

```
class Callback{
    abstract void saveOrUpdate(boolean wasInMap);    
}

public void parse(Map<Integer, String> map) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {    
        String obj = "test";

        Callback callback = (wasInMap) -> { //Java 8 syntax to be short
            if (wasInMap) {
                System.out.println("Update");
                //session.update(map.getKey(j));
            } else {
                System.out.println("add to map " + j);

                map.put(j, obj);
                System.out.println("save");
                //session.save(obj);
            }
        }

        Object returnedValue = map.putIfAbsent(j, callback);

        callback.saveOrUpdate(returnedValue != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like your missing something in your code, I'm not sure where map.putIfAbsent is being populated. Is that coming from my original map? Also, how does that compare to Tarik answer? The only thing I left out in my example was the fact I have several of these maps where I store database lookup values. I'm just doing this to prevent making millions of round trips to the database.

Comment: *Updated the code*. I've moved out the new instance creation from if. Compared to Tarik's answer, I require to do this. In this case there would be no lock during session update, so it should be more performant.

Comment: I'm testing your code and thus far it appears to be working. I want to do some additional test before I mark the answer.

Comment: I just noticed your callback answer, I'm not sure how this would work when I have multiple maps, example yearMap, makeMap, modelMap, etc. Just database lookup values to save on database lookup queries.

Comment: Well, I didn't test this code, but for me it appears to be an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Use the syncronized keyword to ensure that checking if j is in the map and adding it if not, is done atomically. However, it defeats the purpose of multithreading as most threads will be blocked while one thread is looping.

```
public void setupRender() {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

final Map<Integer, String> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, String>());

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            parse(map); 
        }
    });
    System.out.println("map size " + map.size() + " loop " + i);
}
}

public void parse(Map<Integer, String> map) {
    synchronized(map) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if (map.containsKey(j)) {
            System.out.println("Update");
            //session.update(map.getKey(j));
        } else {
            System.out.println("add to map " + j);
            String obj = "test";
            map.put(j, obj);
            System.out.println("save");
            //session.save(obj);
        }
        }

        if (j % 50 == 0) {
            System.out.println("commit");
            //tx.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do the threads still run in parallel? Also, how much of a performance loss is there with synchronized? and lastly in this example I'm only showing a single map, in my real world code there is several of these maps, how would you manage it in that case.

Comment: Yes they run in parallel but most threads will be blocked at the synchronized statement while only one will be looping. In this particular case it makes multithreading completely useless in terms of performance. In case of multiple map, you might indeed gain something but you need to show us some code.

Comment: yes it becomes useless if I can't run the threads in parallel. Unfortunately I don't have the actual code with me, but I'll do my best to explain what I'm doing. Nightly I log into hundreds of ftp servers and grab csv files to be parsed. The data in the map is lookup data, example year, make, model data. I process millions of rows, so rather than query the database for every lookup, I just initialize the maps with the data and search against the map, if it doesn't exsit, I just add it and commit it to the database every 250 rows. I'm trying to process multiple csv files at once.