# What is internal architecture of Concurrent HashMap

Tags: java

I know the internal architecture of Hashmap but varies some how from HashMap becouse this is thread safe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510632/whats-the-difference-between-concurrenthashmap-and-collections-synchronizedmap

Comment: please unhold this so that better answer can be schedule.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact that you shouldn't actually care about the internal architecture of a collections implementation (you should only care about the public API and relevant contract)...

The source code for the JDK library is distributed with the JDK.

You can also browse versions of it online (for example: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashMap.java?av=f)

Have fun.