# Partitioning concurrent HashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I need to store some values category  wise in key-value pair in cache,for eg:
category1 = {(k1,v1),(k2,v2)}
category1 = {(k3,v3),(k4,v4)}

which can be accessed concurrently.
I am looking like partitioning the concurrent HashMap, but dont know exactly what data structure to use.
Any idea?,
Thanks

Comment: Use a separate `Map` for each partition?

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510632/whats-the-difference-between-concurrenthashmap-and-collections-synchronizedmap)

Comment: What about ArrayList of Map, where each map is a category. and arraylist is container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be useful for you,

```
ArrayList<Map> categoryWrapperList = new ArrayList<Map>();
Map category1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
category1.put(1, 2);
category1.put(2, 3);
Map category2 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
category2.put(11, 2);
category2.put(21, 3);
categoryWrapperList.add(category1);
categoryWrapperList.add(category2);
```

Here, Arraylist will store all the categories, and you can put any value in the category. you, obviously can see more about ArrayList for time consumption by arraylist in various operations(like get, search etc).

Comment: we can use map within map,

Comment: Is this a question or suggestion? If question, then yes you can.