# Synchronized on HashMap value object

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

I've got a question about synchronization of objects inside a Map (same objects I later change value of). I want to atomically read, do checks and possibly do updates to a value from a map without locking the entire map. Is this a valid way to work with synchronization of objects?

```
    private final Map<String, AtomicInteger> valueMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Response addValue(@NotNull String key, @NotNull Integer value) {
        AtomicInteger currentValue = valueMap.get(key);
        if (currentValue == null) {
            synchronized (valueMap) {
                // Doublecheck that value hasn't been changed before entering synchronized
                currentValue = valueMap.get(key);
                if (currentValue == null) {
                    currentValue = new AtomicInteger(0);
                    valueMap.put(key, currentValue);
                }
            }
        }
        synchronized (valueMap.get(key)) {
            // Check that value hasn't been changed when changing synchronized blocks
            currentValue = valueMap.get(key);
            if (currentValue.get() + value > MAX_LIMIT) {
                return OVERFLOW;
            }
            currentValue.addAndGet(value);
            return OK;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can also use a `ConcurrentHashMap` or `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510632/whats-the-difference-between-concurrenthashmap-and-collections-synchronizedmap)) to synchronize your map.

Comment: How do you ensure that the value hasn't changed between the get + check until the update/return in a ConcurrentHashMap for example. It should work for the update since you will have the previous value stored and checked when you update but when returning OVERFLOW there should be a possibility that the value has changed before returning unless you lock the access between check and return?

Comment: In your code, it is not clear to me that `currentValue` won't hold a stale value if the `valueMap` is accessed without synchronization (as you have done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see much of a difference between your approach and that of a standard [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) - asides from the fact that `ConcurrentHashMap` has been heavily tested, and can be configured for minimal overhead with the exact number of threads you want to run the code with.

In a `ConcurrentHashMap`, you would use the [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#replace%28K,%20V,%20V%29)`(K key, V old, V new)` method to atomically update `key` to `new` only when the `old` value has not changed.

The space savings due to removing all those `AtomicIntegers` and the time savings due to lower synchronization overhead will probably compensate having to wrap the `replace(k, old, new)` calls within while-loops:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> valueMap = 
      new ConcurrentHashMap<>(16, .75f, expectedConcurrentThreadCount);

public Response addToKey(@NotNull String key, @NotNull Integer value) {
     if (value > MAX_LIMIT) {
        // probably should set value to MAX_LIMIT-1 before failing
        return OVERFLOW; 
     }
     boolean updated = false;
     do {
        Integer old = putIfAbsent(key, value);
        if (old == null) {
             // it was absent, and now it has been updated to value: ok
             updated = true;
        } else if (old + value > MAX_LIMIT) {
             // probably should set value to MAX_LIMIT-1 before failing
             return OVERFLOW;
        } else {
             updated = valueMap.replace(key, old, old+value);
        }
     } while (! updated);

     return OK;
}
```

Also, on the plus side, this code works even if the key was removed after checking it (yours throws an NPE in this case).

Comment: `putIfAbsent()` doesn't return a boolean. Besides, I don't see why you're using `get()`, checking if it returns `null`, and then using `putIfAbsent()`, while you can perfectly use `putIfAbsent()` directly: if it returns `null`,  it means the value wasn't in the map, otherwise it returns the value.

Comment: True on both counts, @Magnamag. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for input. This seems very good except for getting an initial value > MAX_LIMIT.

Comment: Fixed, although I still advocate for overflow setting the value to MAX_LIMIT-1 or so; it is counter-intuitive that `addToKey("x",1000)` may leave a smaller value than `addToKey("x", 10)` due to overflow in the first case.