# Which map implementation to use if multiple threads write to a single map

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, synchronization, concurrenthashmap

In my application I would be using a Map.

- Multiple threads would be writing data to this map. The write operations are too many.
- However, the data that is fed to the map has a different key during every write.
- The data in the map would not be read at any point in the application.
- Once in a while, the content would be dumped to a file.

I would like to know the following :

1. In this case, would it be necessary to synchronize the write method?
2. Does a ConcurrentHashMap suit my needs?
3. If not, what would be the right Map implementation to use in this
   case?

Comment: _"The data in the map would not be read at any point in the application"_ and then _"Once in a while the content would be dumped to a file"_ - so how do you dump to a file without reading the map?

Comment: These two points are incompatible: "The data in the map would not be read at any point in the application" and "Once in a while the content would be dumped to a file".  The content cannot be dumped to a file without reading out the full contents of the map.

Comment: You might also want to consider keeping one map per thread and then merging them when you dump to the file. Then, access to the maps will only block when you dump to the file instead of blocking for every write.

Comment: Do you need to have keys serialized into file, or only values ?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is getting a lot of thumbs up in the answers.  It *probably* suits your need, but that's only if file dumps will never overlap, and if your map does not need to accept `null` as a key.  Also not if you perform any aggregate operations (such as `putAll()` or `clear()`) and require them to appear atomic with respect to the dump-to-file operation.

Comment: @Bollinger - By dumping i mean , the entire content of the map is dumped into the file by calling toString() method on the map and passing this as argument to printwriter.
Only the data is important in the application and so i am doing this .

Comment: @sujith, By "only if file dumps will never overlap" I meant in overlap in *time*, not in data, and in fact I now think that's not so much an issue after all.  There is no reason to believe, however, that any particular mechanism for extracting all the contents of the map (e.g. by using `toString()`) has different characteristics with respect to synchronization requirements than any other one.

Comment: @Bollinger : Thank you for the detailed explanation. This answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Focusing on these points:

> - The data that is fed to the map has a different key during every write
> - The data in the map would not be read at any point in the application

You don't need a `Map` at all. I'm assuming that when you state that the data in the map won't be read, you mean that you're not doing `map.get(someKey)` but instead you will traverse the whole map to store the data in the file (or whatever data source you use).

This point:

> - Once in a while the content would be dumped to a file

Reinforces the recommendation above.

Focusing on this point:

> - Multiple threads would be writing data to this map.The write operations are too many.

The best recommendation is to use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). As implementation, you may use [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

In case you dump the data from the `Map` using Java synchronization and want/need to recover this data in form of a `Map`, then use a `ConcurrentHashMap`. If this is not part of your use case because you will read the data from the file on other ways, then avoid using `Map` and use `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: You missed the part where the whole map is dumped into file. Since keys are also content of the map, i would argue that this answer doesn't address the question correctly.

Comment: @user3360241 since the keys have no purpose since they're always unique, then that part is really pointless. Unless the key is relevant data that cannot be found inside the value of the `Map` (which nobody knows except OP), it doesn't seem good. Or, on the other hand, if it have value, store this *key* in a field in the value and save it as well. Again, the `Map` option is useless for this use case.

Comment: What if the op wanted to rebuild the Map from file within another application ? But as you say key could be embedded into value for most cases, but not for this one.

Comment: @user3360241 since that is not pointed out by OP in the question, then there's no need to address it. Also, it's not that hard to build a map from a file. And OP's never talking about a serialization mechanism.

Comment: @user3360241, a blocking queue is a perfectly fine approach.  It is simply a question of the type of elements to be enqueued.  That could be, for example, a suitably-parameterized `Map.Entry` if need be.

Answer (score 1):

To 1: The [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface does not guarantee any synchronization, especially not on writes. Looking at the non-concurrent implementations ([`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), [`HashTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)), the all state that

> if multiple threads access a map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

To 2 and 3: If you were using a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), you would not have to worry about synchronization. But I agree with [Luiggi Mendoza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31542542/4216641): do not use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. Yes

However i find this is a contradiction:

- The data in the map would not be read at any point in the application
- Once in a while the content would be dumped to a file.

How can you dump to a file without reading it?

I think it's safe to say that ConcurrentHashMap can handle that case anyway, so go for it.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice instead of simply saying "yes" or "no".

Answer (score -1):

If you really need a `Map`, a `ConcurrentHashMap` is what you need. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510695/3252091).

Answer (score -1):

As you said too, ConcurrentHashMap seems meets your requirement. It is thread safe without synchronizing the whole map. Reads can happen very fast while write is done with a lock.

Answer (score -3):

All your keys are unique so you don't necessarily need synchronization for ensuring the integrity of the map but you do need it when you would actually be writing to the file. Use ConccurentHashMap or a normal synchronized map both suit you well. You can do without a Map too simply store key/value in some object and store the object in a synchronized list.

Comment: Having distinct keys in no way means that writes to the map do not require synchronization.

Comment: A quote from e.g. [`TreeMap`'s Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html): *If multiple threads access a map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger and Turing : Yeah I do understand that. My question is, if all keys that are ever going to be inserted and are Unique and the Map is used only for writing purpose what could be the possible harm ? For eg : write from one thread might not be available to the other thread.. fair enough.. the only harm will be when you write to the file as you might not see all updates.. correct ? Did I miss something ? I agree above is not a perfect comment

Comment: It's not merely a question of not seeing updates, though that possible problem should be discounted.  The map's internal state could become *corrupted* by unsynchronized concurrent updates.  The keys all being distinct does not protect from that.  More generally, program behavior is not well defined in the absence of proper synchronization.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : And how probably would the map get corrupted ? Multiple threads writing to the same bucket because hashcode is same ?

Comment: *Any* piece of state modified by multiple threads presents an opportunity for corruption.  Two or more putting items in the same bucket (which does not depend on them having equal hash codes) would certainly produce such a situation.  So also would a thread causing a rehashing to occur as a result of adding an element.  Without studying the implementation, you cannot know what other possibilities there may be.

Comment: @John Bollinger : If multiple threads are writing to the same map , could the data corruption be avoided using ConcurrentHashMap or do the writes still need to be externally synchronized ?

Comment: @sujith, `ConcurrentHashMap` is all about avoiding the need for external synchronization, so the answer to your question is "yes", subject to the provisos I already mentioned in comments on the original post.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : That explains it. Thanks.