# How to easily convert a java8 map to a concurrentMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, concurrency

Is there any way to convert java8 `Map<K,V>` to `ConcurrentMap<K,V>` other than iterating manually over all entities?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510632/whats-the-difference-between-concurrenthashmap-and-collections-synchronizedmap

Comment: accidentally asked the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist the constructor in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html

So you can

> ConcurrentHashMap(Map m) Creates a new map
>   with the same mappings as the given map.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ConcurrentHashMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)` constructor for example to pass in a `Map` and construct a `ConcurrentHashMap` .

[JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need is synchronized view of this map you can use

```
java.util.Collections#synchronizedMap
```

Usually, it isn't what you want, because the performance of "synchronized" map is worse in general. But this solution can solve some cases when you want specifically "synchronized view" for your map.

Comment: what is the difference between "synchronized map"  and "synchronized view"

Comment: @EladBenda, synchronized view is just synchronized proxy for your map