# In JDK1.8, is it necessary to use ConcurrentHashMap on all occasions that require synchronization?

Tags: java

In JDK1.8, is it necessary to use ConcurrentHashMap on all occasions that require synchronization？And never use Collections.synchronizedMap (Map)?

Comment: You use `ConcurrentHashMap` *instead* of synchronization. There is no basis for your supposition.

Comment: You mean instead of `synchronized`, @EJP. `ConcurrentHashMap` is a synchronized structure, it just doesn't use the keyword `synchronized` to achieve synchronization.

Comment: No, it isn't necessary to use one idiom or the other. Use whichever one best suits the needs of the implementation.

Comment: @LewBloch `ConcurrentHashMap` is *not* `synchronized`

Comment: @Andreas It doesn't use the keyword `synchronized`, as I assume you mean by putting the keyword in backticks, but it achieves synchronization without that. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)

Comment: @LewBloch Huh?!? The article you linked defines synchronization as one of two distinct concepts: synchronization of processes (meeting up), and synchronization of data (replication), neither of which fit the concept of synchronization of a `Map`, which is all about *preventing* concurrent access. This is a Java question, and in Java terminology, "synchronization" means the use of `synchronized`. This question is about the difference between "concurrent" and "synchronized" collections, and even the javadoc uses those terms to be distinct from each other.

Comment: @Andreas I agree that it's a terminology issue. There is one context in which it is correct though to refer to it as "synchronized" - use of data in ConcurrentHashMap is "correctly synchronized" in the context of the Java Memory Model specification ([A program is correctly synchronized if and only if all sequentially consistent executions are free of data races.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html))

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Just because "correctly synchronized" requires that "executions are free of data races", does mean that all executions that are free of data races are synchronized.

Comment: @Andreas Actually that's not true: in the JMM, if all sequentially consistent executions are free of data races, then the program is "correctly synchronized". Even if it doesn't encouter any use of Java monitors (`synchronized` keyword) during the execution. You're getting hung up on the word synchronized which does not always mean "the *keyword* `synchronized`", which is the point that both Lew and I have been trying to make to you.

Comment: @LewBloch No, I do *not* mean `synchronized`, and no, it is *not* a synchronized structure, it is a *thread-safe* structure, all achieved without any synchronization at all, *or* `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not *necessary* to replace use of `Collections.synchronizedMap` with `ConcurrentHashMap` when used by multiple threads.

The **Concurrent Collections** section in the javadoc for package [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) says:

> "Synchronized" classes can be useful when you need to prevent all access to a collection via a single lock, at the expense of poorer scalability. In other cases in which multiple threads are expected to access a common collection, "concurrent" versions are normally preferable.

As you can see, both `Collections.synchronizedMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap` can have their uses.

See also "[What's the difference between ConcurrentHashMap and Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510632/5221149)".